DOMContentLoaded event is not firing code outside it working
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript  </title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="App"></div>

    <script src="./index.mjs" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>

index.mjs
console.log("Script loaded");   this is priting only

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");  //nothig prints inside this event
});

I want code inside DOMContentLoaded to work but its not working at all in simple code. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Pretty sure you don't need to wait for DOMContentLoaded inside a module - though I may be wrong

I want to all some fetching api logic inside DOMContentLoaded and show on screen, but it's not logging anything inside it

I was wrong, DOMContentLoaded IS fired - why it's not working for you is a mystery

can this issue be specific to codesandbox as now I tried same code in CodePen  both console statement working there?

Don't know. Never used those sort of sites to test code

Do you have a DOM in the sandbox where your code is not working? If not, then you will not have window or document available. Only in a browser or a client that supports DOM

I can access all other dom functions in sandbox like getelemenbyID and other
